# Replace All Function in C# with Special Character

Tags: c#, regex

When I call

```
Regex.Replace(
    "My [Replace] text and another [Replace]", 
    "[Replace]", 
    "NewText", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

this give me following result I don't why it is giving unexpected result.

> My [NewTextNewTextNewTextNewTextNewTextNewTextNewText] tNewTextxt NewTextnd NewTextnothNewTextNewText [NewTextNewTextNewTextNewTextNewTextNewTextNewText]

How can I change Regex so result can be like this .

My NewText text and another NewText

Comment: why not just use String.Replace if you aren't using the features of RegEx? If it is the case insensitive replacing you need, see this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/fastestcscaseinsstringrep.aspx

Comment: Accepte answer if it works for you

Answer (score 5):

`[]` has special meaning in RegEx; It lets you specify a 'list' of characters/character classes for a match. You need to escape it to make it work like you expect:

```
"\\[Replace\\]"
```

Double back-slashes are used here because the first is to escape the slash for C#, then the second to escape it for the Regex.

This is what your current regex is basically doing: Match any character among these: `R, e, p, l, a, c, e`

That's why you see your `NewText` repeated 7 times, back-to-back, between the square brackets at the beginning of your result text. It's also then simply replacing any occurrence of those 7 characters with `NewText`.

Escaping the `[]` removes the special meaning, so you are matching literally, and exactly what you wish to match.

Comment: I would also echo the comment/answer to the effect that in this case, a simple `String.Replace()` would be simpler. It's easier to use that when you have a plain, simple replacement like this, with no variable patterns to match.

Answer (score 2):

its better to make use of [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) rather than regular expression...........

```
string errString = "This docment uses 3 other docments to docment the docmentation";

        Console.WriteLine("The original string is:{0}'{1}'{0}", Environment.NewLine, errString);

        // Correct the spelling of "document".

        string correctString = errString.Replace("docment", "document");

        Console.WriteLine("After correcting the string, the result is:{0}'{1}'",
                Environment.NewLine, correctString);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are replacing each occurance of a set of characters with your replacement text. Change your call to this:

```
Regex.Replace(
    "My [Replace] text and another [Replace]", 
    @"\[Replace\]", 
    "NewText", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

and it should work like you expect. But Regex is somehow complicated, so a simple "string.Replace" would suit you much better!

Comment: you need to prefix your match text with a @, you need to escape the \ for C#

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this instead:

```
Regex.Replace(
  @"My [Replace] text and another [Replace]", 
  @"\[Replace\]", 
  "NewText", 
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

That way, the [Replace] is treated as literal.

Answer (score 0):

`[` and `]` are [Regular Expression character group operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_classes). it matches any of the characters inside the group.

If you want to literally match `[Replace]` you have to escape the square brackets with a backslash `\`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(\[Replace\])", replacementText);
```

This is telling replace to find a match by using the ( ) and replace '['Replace']' and swap it out with the replacement text.